# Cassandra - Replication Factor vs Nodes Count Relation

Tags: cassandra, replication, datastax, database, nosql

One of my C* cluster design expects nodes to hold between 1 and 2 TBs of data each, and I expect a huge amount of data in a few months. Pretending I can get 1PB of data and that each node will hold 1TB of data, that means I should plan for a 1000x growth over time, and starting from a "misere" **N=3** nodes with **RF=3** for 1TB of data, I would keep adding nodes up to **N=3000** over time.

The high number of nodes involved put some pressures on how to deal with disks/servers failures, keep the cluster healthy and how to perform backups.

---

**Healthy Cluster**

Assuming you don't want any data loss and perform reads/writes with **LOCAL_QUOROM** Consistency Level, using **RF=3** when you have **N<10** nodes is very reasonable, however when you go up with **N** the *MTBF* of your nodes goes down accordingly, so keeping **RF=3** is going to call for troubles and you may want to "upgrade" to **RF=5** or more.

**Q1: What's a good RF that would fight against the decreased MTBF and keep the cluster healthy (and you sleeping peacefully) with say 100 nodes? and 500? and 1000?**

---

**BACKUP**

Making backups of all the nodes seems to be a bit not viable due to the following reasons:

- Doubles the costs of the solution instantly.
- I would backup the redundant data due to the RF of the cluster.

I see no way to remove the redundancy introduced by the RF and backup only the data expect adding another DC to C* with **RF=2** (I could go for RF=1 but if I lose one node all the backup cluster is down). That
would mean adding **2/RF** of the cost of the cluster for backup
purposes which seems to me a good alternative.

**Q2: Are there any other methods to perform this task without increasing too much the cost of the solution?**